# Intersection of Two Arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

Given two arrays, write a function to compute their intersection.

Example:
Given nums1 = [1, 2, 2, 1], nums2 = [2, 2], return [2].

*Note*:

- Each element in the result must be unique.
- The result can be in any order.

I solve it by following code:

```
public int[] intersection(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    if(nums1.length==0 || nums2.length==0){
            return new int[0];
    }
    Arrays.sort(nums1);
    Arrays.sort(nums2);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    int len1 = nums1.length;
    int len2 = nums2.length;
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    while(i1<len1 && i2<len2){
        if(nums1[i1]==nums2[i2]){
            if(!list.contains(nums1[i1]))
                list.add(nums1[i1]);
            i1 ++ ;
            i2 ++;
        }else if(nums1[i1]>nums2[i2]){
            i2 ++;
        }else {
            i1 ++;
        }
    }
    int result[] = toIntArray(list);
    return result;
}
int[] toIntArray(List<Integer> list)  {
    int[] ret = new int[list.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer e : list)  
        ret[i++] = e.intValue();
    return ret;
}
```

First I sort the two arrays.Then I look through the arrays.I think there is a better solution

Comment: TO is neither a forum for homework nor is it for code review. Check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which might better suit your question.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use / have not yet learned of `HashSet`s? They make this quite simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're allowed to use hashsets, it's quite simple, as `a.retainAll(b)` results in `a intersect b`:

```
public Integer[] intersection(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {

    HashSet<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i : nums1) {
        set1.add(i);
    }

    HashSet<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i : nums2) {
        set2.add(i);
    }

    set1.retainAll(set2);

    return set1.toArray(new Integer[set1.size()]);
}
```

Comment: I test your code on leetcode website,but I get a error:   `incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible upper bounds int,Object`

Comment: I use basic way to convert set to array.And your code works.                                             `public int[] toInt(Set<Integer> set) {
     int[] a = new int[set.size()];
     int i = 0;
     for (Integer val : set) a[i++] = val;
        return a;
     }`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution if you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8):

```
Arrays.stream(arr1)
        .filter(x -> Arrays.stream(arr2)
                .anyMatch(y -> y == x)
        )
        .distinct()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Following is a method implementing the same:

```
public static int[] intersection(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return Arrays.stream(a)
            .filter(x -> Arrays.stream(b)
                    .anyMatch(y -> y == x)
            )
            .distinct()
            .toArray();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for that I never use Java8.Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
public Integer[] intersection(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) 
{

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    int len1 = nums1.length;
    int len2 = nums2.length;
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<Java.lang.Math.min(len1,len2);i++)
        for(int j = 0;j<Java.lang.Math.min(len1,len2);j++)
            if(nums1[i] == nums2[j] && !list.contains(new Integer(nums1[i])))
                list.add(k++,nums1[i]);

     return list.toArray(new Integer[foo.size()]);
 }
```

Comment: In fact we use "list.contains(int)" to check if there is a same value in the list.But I think we are wrong because if the value is more than 127,the check is useless

Comment: Because if value is [-128,127]  ,value will be convert into a same Integer object.

Comment: Yes i am check out contains documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: You just don't get my meaning.If value is more than 127,such as [200,200],the values will be convert into two objects

Comment: lol , you are so wrong, integer can contains values between -2^31 to 2^32 haha

Comment: you are talking about char type and you are wrong in that it will become 2 objects...

Comment: If you are a Chinese ,please see [link](http://www.cnblogs.com/dolphin0520/p/3780005.html)

Comment: Do you know the difference between int type and Integer type?

Comment: That Integer is a class type (reference type) and int is a primitive(value type) ,

Comment: Yes,but you use list.contains(int).Java will convert int to Integer

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.You are right.I am very sorry.Thank you for correcting me

Comment: Thats ok, happy to help.